# Webapp clientside architecture in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, architecture

I am looking for some sample client side structure. Do professional web developers follow some client side  architecture design ? Are there function diagrams , class diagrams , flow diagrams ? These all are not required for building a small website but required when building a HUGE webapp where many modules are communicating with each other.

I am building a webapp where client side would use Angularjs/RequireJs/Bootstrap/some Jquery plugins  which has 5-7 independent modules. I am not able to figure out how all should be designed well to work together.

Any ideas what methodologies do large software companies like Google or Apple follow for the same ?

Can someone give a direction that i should be following when architecting/designing a webapp

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into Zendfox Web Application Framework. I got it awesome framework to develop any type and size web application.

Here's [download link](http://www.example.com/)